# How to Define Data Warehouse units in Synapse?

Tags: data-warehouse, azure-synapse

We have DWUs option in Azure synapse for Dedicated SQL Pool, which start from 100 DWUs which as per document consists of Compute +Memory +IO.

but how to check what type of compute node it is ? because in document it says 100 DWU consists of 1 compute with 60 distributions and 60 GB of Memory.

but here what is the configuration of Compute Node ?

or if we can't find the configuration, how to calculate the required DWUs to process 10GB of Data.

Answer (score 0):

How many cores do you think you need to process 10GB data? It's a pretty complicated question to answer.
What are your queries doing? Are you doing 20 self joins? How much tempdb space is needed?
Breast way to find out will be to run experiments for your particular workload and resize such that you use 80% of available resources.

Answer (score -1):

A dedicated SQL pool (formerly SQL DW) represents a collection of analytic resources that are being provisioned. Analytic resources are defined as a combination of CPU, memory, and IO.

These three resources are bundled into units of compute scale called Data Warehouse Units (DWUs). A DWU represents an abstract, normalized measure of compute resources and performance.

> What is the configuration of Compute Node ? And how to check what type of compute node it is?

Each Compute node has a node ID that is visible in system views. You can see the Compute node ID by looking for the node_id column in system views whose names begin with sys.pdw_nodes.

For a list of these system views, see [Synapse SQL system views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sql-data-warehouse-and-parallel-data-warehouse-catalog-views?toc=/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/toc.json&bc=/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true).

> How to calculate the required DWUs to process 10GB of Data.

Dedicated SQL pool (formerly SQL DW) is a **scale-out** system that can provision **vast amounts of compute** and **query sizeable quantities of data**.

To see its true capabilities for scaling, especially at larger DWUs, we recommend scaling the data set as you scale to ensure that you have enough data to feed the CPUs.

For more information, refer to [Data Warehouse Units (DWUs) for dedicated SQL pool (formerly SQL DW) in Azure Synapse Analytics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/what-is-a-data-warehouse-unit-dwu-cdwu#how-many-data-warehouse-units-do-i-need)

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Comment: You copy pasted from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/what-is-a-data-warehouse-unit-dwu-cdwu and then came back to ask for an accept